# jQuery Cycle - #next #prev, goto nextGallery after final slide of currentGallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, cycle, pager

I am using jQuery cycle in several galleries with #next #prev navigation and a image counter output.

Now I am trying to connect all these galleries together. If the user reaches the final slide of gallery A (galleryA.html), the #next anchor should point to gallery B (galleryB.html) / the #prev anchor should point to gallery C (galleryC.html).

How can I combine my 2 functions to do that?

```
// slideshow fx
$(function() {
        $('#slideshow').cycle({ 
        fx:     'fade',
        speed:  350,        
        prev:   '#prev', 
        next:   '#next', 
        timeout: 0,
        after:     onAfter
    });
});
//image counter output
function onAfter(curr,next,opts) {
    var caption = 
        (opts.currSlide + 1) + opts.slideCount;
        $('#counter').html(caption);
}
```

html:

```
<div id="slideshow-container">

<div class="slideshow-nav"><a id="prev" href=""></a></div>
<div class="slideshow-nav"><a id="next" href=""></a></div>

<div id="slideshow" class="pics">
    <img src="galleryA/01.jpg" />
    <img src="galleryA/02.jpg" />
    <img src="galleryA/03.jpg" />
    <img src="galleryA/04.jpg" />
    <img src="galleryA/05.jpg" />
    <img src="galleryA/06.jpg" />
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not too familiar with the cycle plugin, but you could put something like this in `function onAfter`:

```
if(opts.currSlide == opts.slideCount) { 
  $("#next").attr("href","galleryB.html"); 
}
```

or you could try

```
if(opts.currSlide == opts.slideCount) { 
 $("#next").click(function() { document.location = "galleryB.html"; });
}
```

Untested, something along those lines?

Basically it only attaches the redirect behaviour onto `#next` after the last slide has been shown.. There might be an `onFinish` option or something, have you checked the docs?

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I will try all the possibilities along those lines I can come up with.

jQuery Cycle features an end option:
end: null,  // callback invoked when the slideshow terminates (use with autostop or nowrap options): function(options)

I think I am in trouble because I trying to rotate withing image groups and galleries, so the #prev and #next anchors do 2 things, rotate within a group of images and when reaching the end (on either side!) will goto the next or prev gallery.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look here :

http://helpdesk.toitl.com/?p=cycle_plugin

It is not so easy to integrate 2 synchronized cycles in the same page ... In this sample there is no reload of the page with location=... but the 2 galleries are managed using the different commands of the cycle plugin.

Regards,
Dominique VINCENT

Comment: Holy...! Big thanks for your effort and time. It will take me a couple of days to understand everything :-O
I really need to get your JS skills ...